# how to find xsd-type definition using netbeans IDE

Tags: netbeans-8, netbeans-plugins

I have XSD, that includes another XSD.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:include schemaLocation="some.xsd"/>
  <xs:element name="ROOT">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="SOME" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Element SOME defined in some.xsd.
I want to select word SOME, press CTRL+B and go to definition of SOME element in some.xsd.
But it doesn't work.

1. How can I get this functionality (mb plugin)?
2. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a way to do exactly what you want, but there is a NetBeans plugin that gets very close. First, I created two XSD files in an arbitrary NetBeans project:

1. A file named **newXmlSchema.xsd** which contains the data in your sample file, and references a second XSD file named **some.xsd**.
2. The file **some.xsd** contains the following data for demonstration purposes:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <xs:schema version="1.0"
              xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
              elementFormDefault="qualified">
       <xs:element name="SOME">
           <xs:complexType>
               <xs:sequence>
                   <xs:element name="Dob" type="xs:date" />
                   <xs:element name="Address" type="xs:string" />
               </xs:sequence>
           </xs:complexType>
       </xs:element>
   </xs:schema>
   ```

[The **XMLTools4NetBeans** plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/40292/xmltools4netbeans) is not officially supported for NetBeans 8.2, but it works fine. After downloading the plugin:

- Unzip it.
- Add it as a NetBeans plugin: **Tools > Plugins > Downloaded > Add Plugins...**, then select all the ubnzipped ***.nbm** files.
- Restart NetBeans.

After NetBeans has restarted the plugin should be working:

- Open the parent file (**newXmlSchema.xsd**) and position the cursor over the word **SOME**.
- Right-click and select **Go To > Definition** from the context menu. (These menu entries are added when the plugin is installed.)

  [image: parentToChild]
- The source of **some.xsd** opens in a new tab.
- This is not exactly what you want, but unfortunately I don't think it is possible to add a keyboard shortcut for the menu navigation.

The plugin does a lot more than this. For example, you can open the complete XSD definition in a Schema view (note the **Schema** tab on the screen shot above), and render that schema in a column view or a tree view just by clicking a button.

The screen shot below shows how to jump from the tree view of the entire schema to the source containing the SOME element (**some.xsd**):

[image: treeView]

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what I was looking for!